# How to detect a click on the CheckBox in the TListView

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, tlistview

So basically when a user clicks on the checkbox, I want to add that item in my list, I have tried using the OnChange event but this is not working for me as it gets fired even when the Checkbox is not clicked.

My code is simple and straightforward

```
procedure LvUserChange(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;Change: TItemChange);
 var
 objUser : TUsers;
begin
   if not assigned(objListOfChangedUsers) then
   objListOfChangedUsers := TObjectList.Create;

   objUser := Item.Data;
   objListOfChangedUsers.Add(objUser);
end;
```

I want this code to be fired ONLY when the checkbox is clicked in the ListView

Comment: Really? Works for me. Show us your code and explain what unwanted behaviour occurs.

Comment: unwanted behaviour is that the Onchange event fires even though the Checkbox was not clicked as I stated in the question, is there any other event or method I can use?

Comment: You appear to be using the OnChange event rather than the OnClick Event. The OnChange event fires every time the component is changed for whatever reason.

Comment: Does `OnItemChecked` event exist in D2007?

Comment: @Dsm So are you saying I should use the OnClick event? wont this fire even though Im not clicking on the checkbox?

Comment: Sorry - I meant the OnClickCheck event - you are quite right.

Comment: @Dsm I am not aware of this event in D2007

Comment: @MBo I dont think  D2007 has that event

Comment: Do you have an OnItemChecked property? If so, that is the one to use.

Comment: @Dsm that property does not exist in D2007

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Delphi 2009 and later, you can use the [`TListView.OnItemChecked`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.OnItemChecked) event to detect checkbox clicks.  Delphi 2007 does not have such an event, in which case you will need to detect the notification manually in your own code. I will demonstrate with an interposer class, but there are other ways to do this.

```
uses
  ..., CommCtrl, ComCtrls, ...;

type
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  protected
    procedure CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyLV); message CN_NOTIFY;
  end;

....

procedure TListView.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyLV);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.NMHdr.code = LVN_ITEMCHANGED then
  begin
    if (Message.NMListView.uChanged = LVIF_STATE) and
       ( ((Message.NMListView.uOldState and LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK) shr 12)
         <> ((Message.NMListView.uNewState and LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK) shr 12)) then
    begin
      // changing check box state will land you here
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, and how `TListView` implements the `OnItemChecked` event in Delphi 2009+. However, do note that the checkboxes are implemented as state images, and the `OnChanging` and `OnChange` events are fired with `Change=ctState` when an item's checkbox state is (being) changed, and `TListItem` does have a `Checked` property in D2007.

Comment: @David, since this is sort of a hack, is it preferable to put this in a separate unit?

Comment: That's how I'd do it. I'd make a derived class that surfaced the same event as modern Delphi. But it's really up to you how you organise your code.

Answer (score 3):

Since OnItemChecked does not exist, you cannot get your event to fire only when the item is checked, but you can filter your event like this

```
procedure LvUserChange(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;Change: TItemChange);
 var
 objUser : TUsers;
begin
   if Change = ctState then
   begin
     if Item.Checked then
     begin
       if not assigned(objListOfChangedUsers) then
       objListOfChangedUsers := TObjectList.Create;

       objUser := Item.Data;
       objListOfChangedUsers.Add(objUser);
     end
     else
     begin
       // just in case there are any actions when unchecking
     end;
   end;
end;
```

I don't have Delphi 2007 but have checked the documentation and it should work.

Comment: I can confirm this does not work, as the event fires even when the checkbox was not clicked but instead by putting a focus on the "checked" Item, then all the condions becomes true and ends up adding the item to the list